# How do you test js redirects using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

In my controller a redirect is done using the following code:

session controller

```
def create
  render js: "window.location.pathname = #{home_path.to_json}"
end
```

But when I run capybara it doesn't get to the home_page after `login` submit happens:

```
describe "Login Test", :js => true do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
  it 'should show the users first name' do
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'email', with: @user.email
    fill_in 'password', with: @user.password
    click_button "Log In"
    save_and_open_page
    assert page.has_content? @user.first_name
  end
end
```

When I troubleshoot by adding the `launchy gem` and running `save_and_open_page` I get a page with the following text:
`window.location.pathname = "/"`

Capybara gives me the following error:
`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"`

It seems capybara never gets past the login button.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :js => 'window.location.href = "#{home_path.to_json}"' }
end
```